# Create New Firebase Database storage for each new authenticated users

Tags: java, php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Am creating a firebase bank android app where users can authenticate and create account. It's having a Firebase RecyclerView which shows lists of bank transactions in linear layouts in one of my children fragment. Please is there any way i can allow newly authenticated users to create a Firebase Database and storage automatically so that whenever a user (CRUD) **Create,** **Read,** **Update,** and **Delete** an item, it'll delete only from that user's Firebase Database RecyclerView lists then list will refresh automatically for that specific user

Answer (score 0):

You typically won't want to create an entire database for each user, but instead store the data in a way that it is segmented per user, and then sure access to it through Firebase's security rules.

Same for file storage, you'll also want to segment the files per user there and use security rules to control access to the files.

A great starting point for learning more about this is in the Firebase documentation on security rules, under the section on [how to secure data so that only the content-owner has access to it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access), which covers the structure and rules for Realtime Database, Cloud Storage, and Firestore.